# Error when getting parameter from AWS Systems Manager on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

When running a simple command such as

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name mykey
```

I get the error `No module named 'cryptography'`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Run `pip install cryptography` and try again?

Comment: I already did that but it still has the same issue.

Comment: Try reinstalling the AWS CLI?